# EF code-first with 2 non-null Foreign Keys in the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework code first.

I was trying to put 2 foreign keys on the same table but I am not being allowed to do so.

It's like that(edited) :

The table is called `Avaliacao`:

```
[Required]
public int AvaliacaoId { get; set; }


[Required]
public int LivroId { get; set; }
public int? AutorId { get; set; } 

public virtual Livro Livro { get; set; }
public virtual Autor Autor { get; set; }
```

I wanted `AutorId` *not to be null* but it only works that way.

I wish I could have *2 non-nullable FK* but only one `Delete on Cascade`.

How do I achieve this with Entity Framework code-first?

Somebody help me please

thx in advance

ZeCarioca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I have not tested this, but if you  are using EF5 you could make use of the OnModelCreating method by overiding it in your DbContext. You can call the same entity multiple times to add configuration so you could specify a second foreign key, set its HasRequired property and set its WillCascadeOnDelete property to true.

Something like this for the first foreign key.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Avaliacao>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.LivroId)
                .HasForeignKey(m => a.LivroId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Avaliacao>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.AutorId)
                .HasForeignKey(m => a.AutorId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

}
```

For more reference on the method you can look here at the MSDN Docs: [DbModelBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

As mentioned I have not tested this myself so you might need to change some of the properties.

Hope it helps

Comment: There can be good reasons for having the FK id there, too, and EF handles that fine. The OP's code appears to be defining them properly there. As you note, the Livro and Autor classes must also have primary keys, though.

Comment: Dude... this class already has its Primary Key... I want it to have 2 foreign keys that cant be nullable.... i can make that happen in the database but i need to do it with code-first because the c# code only accpets properties that are written in the definition of the class..
i edited the code to be more clear

Comment: now it helped thx a lot...but instead of   .HasRequired(a => a.LivroId) its just Livro... and the same thing for AutorId...But the rest is all right..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the fluent API, for example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasRequired(t => t.Livro);
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasRequired(t => t.Autor);
```